# Express on Node.js aws-sdk.s3.getObject() has empty buffer when using createReadStream() to pipe to res

Tags: node.js, express, aws-sdk

The code in question, first not trying to create a read stream from the response:

```
app.get('/dashboard/downloadfile', requiresLogin, (req, res) => {
  const userid = req.user.id;
  const filename = req.query['file-name'];

  db.getFileKey([userid, filename], (keyres) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
      Key: keyres.rows[0].filekey,
    };
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${ filename }`);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
    s3.getObject(params, (awserr, awsres) => {
      if(awserr) console.log(awserr);
      else console.log(awsres);
    });
  });
});
```

Results of `console.log(awsres);`

```
10:42:27 AM web.1 |  { AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
10:42:27 AM web.1 |    LastModified: 2018-07-23T23:27:29.000Z,
10:42:27 AM web.1 |    ContentLength: 2519,
10:42:27 AM web.1 |    ETag: '"5ebd5ec977c868605a6efe830df8ee0d"',
10:42:27 AM web.1 |    ContentType: 'text/plain',
10:42:27 AM web.1 |    Metadata: {},
10:42:27 AM web.1 |    Body: <Buffer 51 75 65 75 65 20 74 6f 56 69 73 69 74 0d 0a 53 65 74 20 76 69 73 69 74 65 64 0d 0a 0d 0a 0d 0a 66 69 6e 64 5f 6e 75 6d 5f 73 68 6f 72 74 65 73 74 5f ... > }
```

Now with trying to create a read stream from the s3.getObject() response:

```
app.get('/dashboard/downloadfile', requiresLogin, (req, res) => {
  const userid = req.user.id;
  const filename = req.query['file-name'];

  db.getFileKey([userid, filename], (keyres) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
      Key: keyres.rows[0].filekey,
    };
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${ filename }`);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
    s3.getObject(params, (awserr, awsres) => {
      if(awserr) console.log(awserr);
      else console.log(awsres);
    }).createReadStream().pipe(res);
  });
});
```

Results of `console.log(awsres);`

```
10:26:25 AM web.1 |  { AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
10:26:25 AM web.1 |    LastModified: 2018-07-23T23:27:29.000Z,
10:26:25 AM web.1 |    ContentLength: 2519,
10:26:25 AM web.1 |    ETag: '"5ebd5ec977c868605a6efe830df8ee0d"',
10:26:25 AM web.1 |    ContentType: 'text/plain',
10:26:25 AM web.1 |    Metadata: {},
10:26:25 AM web.1 |    Body: <Buffer > }
```

As in the question I'm trying to pipe the file to the client trying to GET the route. Can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: No I can't get the download to start on the client. Client-side I'm using vanilla JS and making http requests using XMLHttpRequest. Uploads are working fine, I'm using the server to generate a signedurl from aws and then the client direct uploads to the s3

Comment: Am I just not understanding something about how streams work? That's definitely a possibility.

Comment: Can you remove the callback from  `s3.getObject`, and just do: `s3.getObject(params).createReadStream()...` I don't know how the lib works internally, but it's possible that you can't use both the callback, which returns the full file, and a stream at the same time.